# How can I fix the number of groups in each page of SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have a Report which displays 6-groups(5-Rows in each Group) of information. The report is having some filter which can be modified by user. When first time report get loads without any filter its page rendering in report viewer and Print page is perfect, But when filters been added in Report information its get unusual.

*Simple explanation given in below image:*

[image]

Could anyone please suggest anything to fix number of rows/groups in each page?

Comment: Is that shaded area with the parameters part of the report? If so, can you move the Brand and Sub Branch rows to the right of the year and month?

Comment: @AlanSchofield: No, it is not shaded and also i can't move it to the right side as per the designing restrictions.

Comment: Is the black box with the `1.Page` a static text field using Global report parameters?  Or does that come from the Dataset?  If it's from the dataset, adding a parent group and adding a group by that field with a page break between groups should fix that.  Also, you should make sure that the report objects containing the groups has `Can-grow` property set to `True`.

Comment: Prevent the filter-info-area from expanding.

Comment: @Steve-o169: Ya its can-grow property is also assigned. But still not working

Comment: @WolfgangKais: Could you please elaborate your comment in answer? I am not getting it exactly!

Comment: What I wanted to say is that obviously this golden(?) area does expand (get higher) when you specify filter criteria. This shifts all other controls on that page downwards, and the last rows (that were meant to be displayed on that page) move to the next page. Therefore, you should try to find a solution to display the filter parameters (if at all) in a way that does not move the layout, Maybe by setting the `CanGrow` property of that area to **`false`**.

Comment: @jap_jap i think you received the answer you are looking for, i don't think there is a way to force the minimum numbers of rows, but you can force maximum numbers. Or you just have to prevent labels from expanding. I think the answer deserve to be accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I will provide two methods to solve the issue*

## (1) Try to prevent the text boxes from expanding

I will assume that you are showing the report parameters *(filters)* as mentioned in the following link:

- [Include Report Parameter Selection Values in Report Output for SQL Server Reporting Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3518/include-report-parameter-selection-values-in-report-output-for-sql-server-reporting-services/)

Then, you should set `CanGrow` property to `False` from the Textbox properties pane as mentioned in folowwing article:

- [Allow a Text Box to Grow or Shrink (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/allow-a-text-box-to-grow-or-shrink-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

[image]

Also make sure that `Allow height to increase` property is not checked in the [Text Box Properties Dialog Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd220561(v=sql.100))

[image]

**Helpful links:**

- [How to prevent a textbox from expanding horizontally?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fb80d84e-45a0-40e1-a4d9-39044b4d32a5/how-to-prevent-a-textbox-from-expanding-horizontally?forum=sqlreportingservices)
- [Text Boxes (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/text-boxes-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

## (2) Limit the number of rows per page

*While searching on this issue, i found the following solution which can be used as a workaround to distribute rows per pages:*

You can specify the limit number of rows per page with a conditional approach. If it is the first page then `10` *(2 groups)* as example, and for other pages `15` *(3 groups)*.

You should follow these steps:

1. Go to `Report` >> `Report Properties` >> `Code` , in the `Custom Code` section, enter the following:

   ```
   Public Function PageNumber() as String
       Dim str as String
       str = Me.Report.Globals!PageNumber.ToString()
       Return str
   End Function

   Public Function TotalPages() as String
       Dim str as String
       str = Me.Report.Globals!TotalPages.ToString()
       Return str
   End Function
   ```
2. Now create your Group with Page Break as below SSRS expression:

   ```
   = IIf ( CInt(Code.PageNumber()) = 1, Ceiling((RowNumber(Nothing)) / 10), Ceiling((RowNumber(Nothing)) / 15) )
   ```

The result will be like the following image:

[image]

**References and helpful links**

- [SSRS Limit Number of rows Per Page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/14631343-b364-4b2d-bdfa-c8815b19d6b3/ssrs-limit-number-of-rows-per-page?forum=sqlreportingservices)
- [Display a fixed number of rows per page for an SSRS report](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3493/display-a-fixed-number-of-rows-per-page-for-an-ssrs-report/)
- [Group Expression Examples (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/bb630426(v=sql.110))
- [Displaying Fixed Number of Rows per SSRS Report Page](https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/11/displaying-fixed-number-of-rows-per-ssrs-report-page.html)

## (3) Update based on the OP comments

Another method to keep group rows on the same page is by setting the `Keep together` propery to true:

```
Row_Group >> Properties >> Keep together = True.
```

Comment: thanks a lot, your second suggestions worked. but another solution also i found that can help others. `Row_Group` → `Properties` → `Keep together` set 'True'. Bydwy thanks a lot for your precious time for the solution.

Comment: @jap_jap i will add this to the answer so it will be more informative